# Asp.net Web Api (noncore) import to Azure APIM

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, azure-app-service-plans, azure-webapps

We have a asp.net web api ( non core) published in Azure App service . Now I am trying to configure these API's in Azure APIM. How can i import all the operations under this API to APIM instead of manually adding each operations one at a time . I explored the option of OpenAPI however since non core Web API doesn't support this , Is there an alternate way to handle.

Answer (score 1):

It's not required to use .NET core in order to import operations in your API Management. You can work with different programming languages too. What you need to do is document the operations using Swagger (which is supported in non .net core apps).

Here are a few links that may help you:

https://www.andrewhoefling.com/Blog/Post/web-api-swagger-swashbuckle

http://wmpratt.com/swagger-and-asp-net-web-api-part-1/